# I have two data structures that have some duplicated information. Is there a way to reduce this duplication using .map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

My task is to create a function that will convert numbers to roman numerals. I'm able to do this using two data structures, but I want to accomplish this using one. I know the .map can help, but I'm not too familiar with it.

```
function romanCovertion(num) {

  // let nums = [ 1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1 ];
  // let romanNums = [ 'M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', 'C', 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I' ];
  // original arrays above

  let romanNums = [[1000, 'M'], [900, 'CM'], [500, 'D'], [400, 'CD'], [100, 'C'], [90, 'XC'], [50, 'L'], [40, 'XL'], [10, 'X'], [9, 'IX'], [5, 'V'], [4, 'IV'], [1, 'I']]

  let myMap = new Map(romanNums)
  //console.log(myMap.get(1000))

  let roman = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    let element = nums[i]
    while (element <= num) {
      roman += romanNums[i];
      //console.log(roman)
      num -= element;
      //console.log(num)
    }
  }
  return roman;
}

//romanCovertion(11)
```

Comment: To understand how to interact with a `Map` you can take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). It provides `.set()` and `.get()` methods.

Comment: I think your problem is specific to your implementation of roman numeral conversion rather than the `.map` functionality itself. Please edit your question/title accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the map using `for .. of` as follows:

```js
function romanConvertion(number) {
  const map = new Map([[1000, 'M'], [900, 'CM'], [500, 'D'], [400, 'CD'], [100, 'C'], [90, 'XC'], [50, 'L'], [40, 'XL'], [10, 'X'], [9, 'IX'], [5, 'V'], [4, 'IV'], [1, 'I']]);
  let result = '';

  for (const [arabic, roman] of map) {
    while (arabic <= number) {
      number -= arabic;
      result += roman;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(romanConvertion(11));
console.log(romanConvertion(954));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.map` is mostly for when you need to modify each element in the array.

In your implementation `.reduce` or `.forEach` is more appropriate since your array will serve as a look up table instead of the actual data that needs to be modified that serves as the result.

```
function romanConvertion(num) {
    let romanNums = [
        [1000, 'M'],
        [900, 'CM'],
        [500, 'D'],
        [400, 'CD'],
        [100, 'C'],
        [90, 'XC'],
        [50, 'L'],
        [40, 'XL'],
        [10, 'X'],
        [9, 'IX'],
        [5, 'V'],
        [4, 'IV'],
        [1, 'I']
    ];
    var result = romanNums.reduce((x, roman) => {
        while (roman[0] <= num) {
            num -= roman[0];
            x += roman[1];
        }
        return x;

    }, '');

    return result;
}
```